# Accelerometer with acceleration - move image Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, accelerometer

Developing a very simple-learning game for Windows Phone 8 in C#, I have created an acceleration vector like this:

```
Vector3 acceleration = accelerometerReading.Acceleration;
```

I cannot do anything like:

```
mycontrol.Xacceleration = mycontrol.Xacceleration + acceleration.X * 200;
```

How can I apply that acceleration to an image, I cannot find any coordinates or acceleration property. I am trying to move an image, like in a labyrinth game, how can I achieve this with the acceleration? How can I apply it?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make a game with moving objects, you should look into using XNA or a game engine like Unity because the performance of C#/XAML will not be good.
If you really want to use C#/xaml you will need to calculate the postion of your image control yourself. To set the position you can put your image inside a Canvas and set the position like this:

```
Canvas.SetTop(myControl,XPosition);
Canvas.SetLeft(myControl,YPosition);
```

You can also use StoryBoard to animate the objects but it will probably be more complex if the acceleration and direction keep changing

To take advantage of hardware acceleration you will need to set CacheMode="BitmapCache" on the moving object.

Here is some code to calculate the object position:

```
public class ObjectInfo
    {
        public Vector2 Position { get; set; }
        public Vector2 Speed { get; set; }
        public Vector2 Acceleration { get; set; }
    }


    private DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer;
    private int refreshTimeMilisecond = 100;
    private ObjectInfo myObject;

    public void Init()
    {
        myObject = new ObjectInfo();
        dispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
        dispatcherTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(refreshTimeMilisecond);
        dispatcherTimer.Tick += dispatcherTimer_Tick;
    }

void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myObject.Position = myObject.Position + myObject.Speed*refreshTimeMilisecond;
        myObject.Speed = myObject.Speed + myObject.Acceleration * refreshTimeMilisecond;

        Canvas.SetTop(myControl, myObject.Position.X);
        Canvas.SetLeft(myControl, myObject.Position.Y);
    }
```

In xaml:

```
<Canvas>
    <Image x:Name="myControl" CacheMode="BitmapCache" Source="SmyleyImagePath"/>
</Canvas>
```

You will need to play with the refreshTimeMilisecond  parameter to find out what work the best

Comment: I'll try to get it working, but how can i convert the acceleration into coordinates? I could use xna or something similar, its just that i dont like developing with just code and code and code, i like some graphic design as well - and unity pro is way to expensive for now

Comment: updated my response to get you started on how to calculate the position

Comment: Wouch, thank you SO much! I'm gonna spend some time figuring out this and try to get everything to work. Thanks again:)

Comment: @BenoitCatherinet can you please explain your answer in more details. i am trying to achieve something same for a wp8 game. I have a smiley face in the middle of the screen which i want to move around using the accelerator data. i am confused about he myControl, Canvas.SetTop, myObject. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Added the xaml code to define myControl. myObject is just an object used to store the position/speed/acceleration information.